# What are the differences between Open Embedded Core and meta-openembedded

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

Until now, I am still really confused between the recipes in Openembedded-core vs the one in meta-openembedded. And many time, have trouble to put the recipes in the right directory.  They are really similar yet seem to be so different in the content of recipes.

[OpenEmbedded Core](https://www.yoctoproject.org/tools-resources/projects/openembedded-core) contains base layer of recipes, classes and associated files that is meant to be common among many different OpenEmbedded-derived systems, including the Yocto Project.

[meta-openembedded](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/about/) is a collection of layers for the OE-core universe

What are the differences of content of these two metadata?  And why do they have to separate into two metadata?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the start of the OpenEmbedded Project, there was only one set of recipes. By 2010, the sheer size of the meta-data was a problem. (You can see the old repository here: https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded)

The start of the Yocto Project provided manpower to do something OpenEmbedded had talked about for years, start splitting the recipes into useful and easier to maintain subsets. Openembedded-core are the set of recipes that most people need to use to build a small, useful embedded device. Meta-openembedded was everything else. The meta-openembedded layers are used to extend the capability of openembedded-core by increasing the number of recipes to build more software for your project.

Since then, we have been working on meta-openembedded to divide it into smaller groups of recipes grouped by technology, which is why meta-openembedded contains several layers now.